# Is it safe to put secret in the rippled sign command

Tags: ripple

in the rippled api document  https://ripple.com/build/rippled-apis/#sign[rippled sign](https://ripple.com/build/rippled-apis/#sign)
For the sign command, there is an optional parameter 'secret',
I have a conern, if it is presented, is it safe?

Answer (score 0):

As documented in your link:

> Caution: Unless you run the rippled server yourself, you should do
>   local signing with RippleAPI instead of using this command. An
>   untrustworthy server could change the transaction before signing it,
>   or use your secret key to sign additional arbitrary transactions as if
>   they came from you.

So if it is just safe when you are calling this method on your own server. You should never call this command and send your seed, secret, or passphrase to a public server.